# How do I add external links to the images in this piece of code?

Tags: javascript, css, html, image, hyperlink

I am working on a slideshow/carousel for my website. I found this code online and would like to know how to add links to the images presented in the slideshow. I am open to any other suggestions for slideshows.

```
    <!-- Showcase/Banner Image -->
<section id="banner">
        <script>
var i = 0; // Start point
var images = [];
var time = 2500;
// Image List
images[0] = 'simpleslideshow/slide1.jpg';
images[1] = 'simpleslideshow/slide2.jpg';
images[2] = 'simpleslideshow/slide3.jpg';
images[3] = 'simpleslideshow/slide4.jpg';
// Change Image
function changeImg(){
    document.slide.src = images[i];
    if(i < images.length - 1){
        i++;    
    } else {
        i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}
window.onload = changeImg;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment and read up on [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) as well as [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just add the exact url instead of relative url e.g simpleslideshow/slide1.jpg to http://yourdomain.com/imagepath.jpg